# How can I open link directly using php 'echo'? Is there any way to open link directly rather than page with hyperlink text?

Tags: php, html

This gives hyperlink 'nextpage'

```
$link_address = '#';
echo '<a href="$link_address">nextpage</a>';
```

Is there any way so that I can open 'nextpage' directly rather than page with hyperlink text?

Comment: I am using html for my login page and I want to open another page in   " .htm" rather than the hyperlink text while 'submit' button is clicked.                                          I'm sorry if this does not explain clearly.                       And thank you in advance.

Comment: Please add some further explanation to your answer. PHP won't open links

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want is to redirect to a page automatically you can use the `header` function with the `Location` option, remember to insert it before the html

```
<?php
header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
exit;
?>
```

To know more about `header` you can look at it on the official php page
[Php Header Info](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure that I understand your question.  There are several ways you can do hyperlinks using PHP and HTML.  I'm confident that I will be able to help you with this.

You could use the PHP link() function in this way:

```
<?php
$target = "text.txt";
$linkname = "mylink";

link($target, $linkname);
?>
```

Can you provide any more of an example ?